# How big is my Windows 10 hibernation file right now, as a percentage?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, hibernate

I can easily change the size of the hibernation file "hiberfil" in a command prompt using powercfg -h size %. But surely there's a command to **tell me the current size** of it in that same measurement? If not, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To see the size of the file with a command, open a command prompt, go to the root location of the file (like D:) and use the dir command with parameters to display hidden files: 
`dir *.* /A H S`

Or from any path, read directly the desired location:
`dir D:\*.* /A H S`

In this way, you can see the size of hidden/system files like pagefile.sys and hiberfil.sys.

To only show info on that specific file, use:

`dir hiberfil.sys /A H S` or `dir D:\hiberfil.sys /A H S`

Comment: Thanks. I don't think this quite covers what I was wondering, but it's close. You can set the size of the hiber file as a percentage of... something, but you can't ask what the current percentage is.